# Does $\lim \limits_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} \frac{(x+y)(y + (x+y)^2)}{y - (x+y)^2}$ exist?

Tags: calculus, limits

Evaluate
$$\lim \limits_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} \frac{(x+y)(y + (x+y)^2)}{y - (x+y)^2}$$

I can see that the repeated limits are both zero but I'm unable to prove that the simultaneous limit exists and is zero. I have tried converting the expression to polar co-ordinates too but that was equally fuzzy.

Comment: What happens when you choose $x = \sqrt{y} - y$ for $y > 0$?

Comment: Got it! Thanks Daniel. How did you come up with that substitution? Could you plz explain the thinking behind it?

Comment: When you have a fraction, it's always interesting whether you can make the denominator vanish (and if so, where). Solving $y = (x+y)^2$ isn't wizardry, then. If you can't make it vanish, making it as small (in absolute value) as possible (write one coordinate as a function of the other to make it small, here $y = x^2$ gives you something nice too) tends to also shed light on the limiting behaviour.

Comment: @DanielFischer, I now understand the thought process behind the substitution. Basically, you just checked when the denominator vanishes and then the limit won't exist when origin is approached along that path since the function itself becomes undefined along that path.

Comment: That made it particularly striking. If that hadn't been possible, $y = x^2$ would have given a finite nonzero limit along that path.

Answer (score 1):

The point $(0,0)$ is a limit point of the domain of the function under consideration so the question is correctly formulated. Because the Maple command

```
limit(eval((x^3+3*x^2*y+3*x*y^2+y^3+x*y+y^2)/(-x^2-2*x*y-y^2+y), y = -x+1/2-(1/2)*sqrt(-4*x+1)+x^5), x = 0)
```

produces $\infty$ and the Maple command

```
limit(eval((x^3+3*x^2*y+3*x*y^2+y^3+x*y+y^2)/(-x^2-2*x*y-y^2+y), y = x), x = 0)
```

outputs $0$ and the curves $y=-x+1/2-1/2\,\sqrt {-4\,x+1}+{x}^{5},\,y=x$ belong to the domain for small $x$, the double limit under consideration does not exist.